# Enable inline edit on list view

Tags: list-view, inlineeditsupport

Iknow that to be able to enable inline edit on list view i need to ensure the following :

- The edit button is not overriden by a custom VF
- the recordtype (if any) be included in the filter criteria
- Enable Enhanced Lists in the user interface setting
- enable "Mass Edit from Lists" in profile.

But actually all the condition are met. I don't have recordtypes define , and my edit button is not overriden. I am a system admin, and my user interface setting is correct as i cross-checked with my other sansbox where this is working well. When i deployed to my full sandbox org, I loose the inline edit on my list view. What may i be missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer. There were another point to consider :

- the field should be on the page layout

I forgot to deploy the page layout, thus the inline edit was not available as there were no field on the original layout

Comment: I believe you should also select "Enable Inline Editing" in User Interface!

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have include profile with your change set. include system administrator profile while deploying